# $ f(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2})=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2 \Rightarrow f(x)=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> $ f(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2})=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2 \Rightarrow f(x)=?$

I'm getting a wrong answer even though my solution looks valid to me:

Inverse of $(1+\frac{1}{x^2})$ is $(\frac{1}{{\sqrt{x-1}}})$, so I plug this expression in wherever I see $x$'s

$$f(x)=(\frac{1}{{\sqrt{x-1}}})^2+(\sqrt{x-1})^2-2$$

Finally, I get $f(x)=\frac{(x-2)^2}{x-1}$ which is wrong according to the answer key. The answer should have been $x^2-4$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the domain of $f$?

Comment: It is not given in the problem. I'm assuming real numbers

Comment: Since $h(x)= (x^2+1)/x^2 = 1+x^{-2}$ is for $x \ne 0$ always positive, even $h(x) > 1$ for $x \neq 0$. You can say nothing about $f(x)$ for $x \le 1$.

Comment: Do note that the answer key is wrong too. Exchange $x \to \tfrac{x^2+1}{x^2}$ in $x^2 -4$. You don't get that answer either.

Comment: It seems that $\frac{x^2+1}{x^2}$ is a typo or something. If it were $\frac{x^2+1}{x}$, then the answer key makes sense.

Comment: @Song I agree, probably, that is what happened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion your answer is correct. Mimicking your computations I got the same result.

Defining $t=\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2}$ we got that $$x^2=\dfrac{1}{t-1}.$$ So

$$f(t)=f\left(\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{t-1}+t-1-2=\frac{(t-2)^2}{t-1}.$$

This holds for any $t\in (1,\infty)$ assuming $x\in \mathbb R\setminus \{0\}.$

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is correct. I solved the problem like this:
$$f(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2})=f(1+\frac{1}{x^2})=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2$$
Now $f(1+\frac{1}{x^2})$ can be written as a function of just $\frac{1}{x^2}$ so,
$$f(1+\frac{1}{x^2})=g(\frac{1}{x^2})=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}-2$$

Put $t=\frac{1}{x^2}$, to get:
$$f(1+t)=g(t)$$
$$g(t)=t+\frac{1}{t}-2$$
Or, $$g(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}-2$$
Now, $g(x)=f(1+x)$
Put, $1+x=\alpha$ to get,
$$f(\alpha)=g(\alpha-1)=\alpha -1 + \frac{1}{\alpha-1} -2$$

$$f(x)=x - 1 + \frac{1}{x-1} -2$$
$$f(x)=\frac{(x-2)^2}{x-1}$$ where $x\neq 0$,$x\neq1$

Hope this helps...